# Power Query Refresh Changing Format of Column in Table

Tags: excel, powerquery, sumifs

I have a list of dates pulling into an Excel table via Power Query. I've then added columns to that table in Excel (i.e. not in Power Query) that pull in values via SUMIFS. I format all of those columns as currency, but when I refresh data via the Power Query, one of those columns keeps re-formatting itself to short date.

The formula in the column is nothing unique, it's just two SUMIFS pulling in data from another table if it matches the date found in the Power Query column. The Sum range referenced in the formula is formatted as currency, so it's not that.

A bit stumped I'm afraid, as I've never seen this before! Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the 'Preserve cell formatting' option checked in the external data source properties?

Comment: I did, have unticked it and that's fixed it, thanks!